# Convertir Array a DataTable Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Dim array() as Object
```

Lo lleno mediante un:

```
webservice.execute(Parm1).ToArray
```

Quiero pasar ese array a un `DataTable` de una manera dinámica y eficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear el DataTable, y recorrer el Array añadiendo filas al DT.
2. Utilizar la siguiente función:

   ```
   Public Shared Function GetDataTableFromArray(ByVal array As Object()) As DataTable
       Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
       dataTable.LoadDataRow(array, True)
       Return dataTable
   End Function
   ```